# Aligning a footer on the outside text margins

Tags: margins, header-footer

Does anybody know how to align an header/footer on the outside of the text margins? For example:

```
\fancyfoot[LO]{\footnotesize \thepage~{\color{red}\vline}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\footnotesize {\color{red}\vline}~\thepage}
```

What I want is to fix the position of `\vline` on the text-width, and make `\thepage` left (or right) align on the outside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\fancyfoot[LO]{\footnotesize\leavevmode\llap{\thepage~}\textcolor{red}{\vline}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\footnotesize\textcolor{red}{\vline}\rlap{~\thepage}}
```